# Gas Forced Hot Air seems to be blowing extremely hot air

Tags: hvac

Gas forced hot air. The floor registers are hot to the touch after 6 minutes heat running, if left hand on register would burn quickly. Don't remember it being this hot before.

Comment: A thermometer will give an objective basis to determine if anything should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return air -- ensure the filter is clean and the flow through the return grille(s) is good. A furnace should have high temperature cut-out and possibly even low airflow safeties, but I suppose these could be absent, failed, or bypassed.

Answer (score 1):

I find the furnace filter is very dirty or someone installed a HEPA style that creates too much back pressure reducing the air flow. Some systems do get quite warm, if your system has the correct / clean filter the fan motor bearings may need some lube this is the other thing that can reduce the air flow if a direct drive fan or a loose belt, but most of the time I have found filters that had not been changed.